# SQL Server 2008 modify system stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have inherited maintenance of a SQL Server (2008), and I want to modify some of the system stored procedures. These are user-defined system stored procedures (for example: sys.sp_customproc). I can only assume they were created as system procedures so they could be shared across multiple databases? But regardless, I need to modify them.

Here is an example of one of them.

```
USE [msdb]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [sys].[sp_dbmmonitorhelpmonitoring]    Script Date: 06/12/2013 13:16:52 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [sys].[sp_dbmmonitorhelpmonitoring] 
as
begin
set nocount on
if (is_srvrolemember(N'sysadmin') <> 1 )
    begin
        raiserror(21089, 16, 1)
        return (1)
    end

declare @freq_type              int,    -- 4 = daily
        @freq_interval          int,    -- Every 1 days 
        @freq_subday_type       int,    -- 4 = based on Minutes
        @freq_subday_interval   int,    -- interval
        @job_id                 uniqueidentifier,
        @schedule_id            int,
        @retention_period       int,
        @jobname                nvarchar( 256 )

select @jobname   = isnull( formatmessage( 32047 ), N'Database Mirroring Monitor Job' )

select @job_id = job_id from msdb.dbo.sysjobs where name = @jobname
if (@job_id is null)    -- if the job does not exist, error out
begin
    raiserror( 32049, 16, 1 )
    return 1 
end

select @schedule_id = schedule_id from msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules where job_id = @job_id
select  @freq_type = freq_type,
        @freq_interval = freq_interval, 
        @freq_subday_type = freq_subday_type,
        @freq_subday_interval = freq_subday_interval
    from msdb.dbo.sysschedules where schedule_id = @schedule_id

-- If the frequency parameters are not what we expect then return an error
-- Someone has changed the job schedule on us
if (@freq_type <> 4) or (@freq_interval <> 1) or (@freq_subday_type <> 4)
begin
    raiserror( 32037, 16, 1)
    return 1
end

select @freq_subday_interval update_period

return 0
end
```

When I try to execute it, I get the error:

Msg 208, Level 16, State 6, Procedure sp_dbmmonitorhelpmonitoring, Line 46
Invalid object name 'sys.sp_dbmmonitorhelpmonitoring'.

My login is 'sa', I am mapped to the user 'dbo' in the [msdb] database. How do I modify this stored procedure?

Comment: Well it's simple : there is no stored procedure named `sys.sp_dbmmonitorhelpmonitoring` in the database you where you execute this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot alter a SP once you have marked it as a "system stored procedure".  Instead, you have to drop it, recreate it and mark it as a system stored procedure again (using sp_ms_marksystemobject).
I'm sure you already realize how very dangerous it is to mess with anything that has been marked as "system".  I feel obliged to **strongly recommend that you make plenty of backups before you attempt any of this**.  Namely, back up: master, model and MSDB.